# How can I install a motion sensor for a closet light?

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

I am a total noob when it come to house fixing stuff.

I want to add some more lighting to my closet.
Rather than place a small light bulb with the switch on my closet, 
I want the light to turn on automatically using some kind of sensor.

I know that I have to buy

- a light bulb,
- and a motion detector

I am not sure how to set up the sensor to trigger the lightbulb.
Can someone please give me some advice on that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain a bit better. Is there a light there now? Have you done any electrical work at all? Do you have any experience with this kind of work?

Comment: Nothing is there at the moment. How hard could this be ?

Comment: _"How hard could this be ?"_ @evoque2015, sorry, I don't answer loaded questions. What do you know about electrical work and codes?

Comment: Then u don't have to answer it. :)

Comment: Well, since you will not answer my questions I will assume you know absolutely zero about electrical work. Therefore I will refrain from further advice since IMO this is not really a good first time project without some on-site help. The battery options given by Len are your best bet.

Comment: Lowes motion sensor puck lights or cabinet lights...I just installed a few they work great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are ten of the better rated [LED lighting units](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/10-affordable-easy-ways-to-add-lighting-to-a-closet-without-wiring-190664) available today, some utilizing touch/tap to power on and others with motion-detection.

SUMMARY - 10 Affordable & Easy Ways to Add Lighting to a Closet Without Wiring

1. Mr. Beams Indoor/Outdoor Motion-Sensing LED Ceiling Light - $19.99
2. Wireless Motion Sensor Light - 10 Super-Bright LED - $6.57
3. Sierra Tools Battery-Operated Ceiling/Wall Light with Remote - $32.95
4. Utilitech Battery Powered Cabinet LED Puck Light Kit - $11.98
5. Sylvania LED Silver Light Flute Horizontal Light Stick - $11.97
6. Hipe 8 LED Automatic Motion-sensing Night Light - $13.99
7. Superbrite Touch Light - $7.98
8. Wireless Motion-Detecting Light - $39.98
9. Megabrite Wireless Motion Sensor LED Lights - $29.37
10. HDE Motion-Detecting LED Light w/ IR Radial Sensor - $7.06

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer by adding parts of the link into the answer? We want to prevent link rot (where if the link dies this answer becomes useless and irrelevant), so try to add some of that into the answer.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say if you already had lighting in your closet or not.  If you don't, I would suggest buying a stick-up (battery-operated) LED light with a motion sensor.  (In my area, most retailers have several models like this.)

Most interior motion sensors are combined with a switch, so if you don't want a switch then you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one nearby then I think you should have a look at Ikea.
They have a range of affordable low voltage LED lighting systems many of which have integrated sensors which turn on/off the light when a door is opened/closed

I understand they use an infrared sensor of some sort to detect the proximity of the door.

Links are for Ireland, but I'm sure you can find the same for your local store.

Here is the selection of lighting they offer
http://www.ikea.com/ie/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/bedroom_integrated_lighting/

This one, may be of interest as it has integrated sensors,
http://www.ikea.com/ie/en/catalog/products/00267626/

This might be an earlier model, but there are lots of discussions and youtube videos online for reference.
h-ttp://leothoughts.blogspot.ie/2013/01/another-sensor-light-ikea-komplement.html

Hope you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Most people find that a switch that activates when the closet door opens is simpler, easier, and more efficient than what you are describing.